# What are corresponding Frequency values for soundInstance.Pitch in XNA framework?

Tags: audio, xna, frequency

I am developing a winForm application referencing xna framework. I want to play a .wav file at different frequencies. But soundInstance.Pitch values are from -1 to +1. I need corresponding Hertz values i.e. +1 = ???Hz like that. Can anybody help me in this problem!

Answer (score 1):

The Pitch value represents a pitch shift for an existing sound in octaves and does not correspond to an absolute pitch in hertz.

[MSDN - SoundEffectInstance.Pitch Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.pitch.aspx)

Comment: What I understand by it, is that the pitch mentioned here is sample rate. When Pitch is 0f it is 440.1, when +1f it is 880 and When -1f it is 220. Am I right?

Comment: referred to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359881/converting-a-frequency-into-a-1-1-float

Comment: Yes, that's what I said ;)

Comment: thanks, but what i need is frequency from 20 Hertz to 20,000 Hertz. Can I do it in c# with xna framework otherwise please suggest any suitable audio API.

Comment: http://www.david-gouveia.com/creating-a-basic-synth-in-xna-part-i/ This series explains how to create a synth in XNA 4.0 - its pretty involved, you have to create the sine wave yourself.